# Common Multiples between Irrational and Rational Numbers and Concurrency Control

Tags: irrational-numbers, symbolic-computation

This question slightly deviates in the world of computers and programming. So maybe I'll have to ask this elsewhere. I've recently learned that if *a* is a positive rational number and *b* is a positive irrational number, there exists no common multiple between the two.

---

A common design consideration in threaded or embedded systems is concurrency control, when two functions or threads share resources.

So if function A runs every sqrt(2) seconds, and function B runs every 1 second, they will never run at the same time.

Is it somehow possible to use very accurate measured numbers, to make this possible? Or is it possible using exact/symbolic programs/tools? Or is it not possible at all in machine/computer computational formats?!

Comment: Do you assume that the time function A needs to run is an infinitesimal?

Comment: @martin.koeberl I guess that's a good question. Yeah let's assume each function is infinitesimal or one clock cycle on the choice of hardware